# Analyzing Inflow and outflow of parts

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

We have a need to analyze the consumption of a part. The data I have, is taken from our ERP system. The idea is to find "holes" where there is too much stock in the future.

```
Part_number Sign Count Date
4711        B    100   12.04.2019
4711        -    2     16.04.2019
4711        -    1     18.04.2019
4711        -    3     01.05.2019
4711        -    5     14.05.2019
4711        -    1     18.05.2019
4711        +    25    23.05.2019
4711        -    7     24.05.2019
4711        -    1     01.06.2019
4711        -    1     14.06.2019
4711        -    6     15.06.2019
4711        +    15    23.07.2019
4711        -    7     24.07.2019
4711        -    3     01.08.2019
4711        -    25    14.08.2019
4711        -    6     15.08.2019
4712        B    10    12.04.2019
4712        -    2     13.04.2019
4712        -    3     14.04.2019
4713        …    …     …
```

Column descriptions:

- Part_number => self-explaining I guess
- Sign

  - "B" Current Stock,
  - "-" Part used to build an order,
  - "+" New parts ordered and planned arrival date
- Count => Amount
- Date => Planned date in the future

My idea is to separate the data in sections. A sections starts whenever there's a positive change to the stock, like an arriving order, and it ends with the next positive change to the stock. 
The first and last section are an exception. The first section starts with todays date and ends with the next positive change. The last section starts with the last positive change and ends with the last data row.

I'd expect a table of sections based on the data above to look like this.

```
Part_number Section Date_start  Date_end
4711        1       12.04.2019  23.05.2019
4711        2       23.05.2019  23.07.2019
4711        3       23.07.2019  15.08.2019
4712        1       12.04.2019  14.04.2019
```

To find the "holes" the count column should be summed up which results in the following table

```
Part_number Section Date_start  Date_end   Sum
4711        1       12.04.2019  23.05.2019 88   <= 100-2-1-3-5-1
4711        2       23.05.2019  23.07.2019 98   <= 88+25-7-1-1-6
4711        3       23.07.2019  15.08.2019 72   <= 98+15-7-3-25-6
4712        1       12.04.2019  14.04.2019 5    <= 10-2-3
```

Our database server is a Microsoft Sql Server 2016.

Currently I'm using a cursor construction to massage the data and get what I want. As you might imagine this is probably not the best approach. I'd like to improve this query and I'm looking forward to any hints I can get.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use aggregation and window functions.  The key is defining the section, which appears to be a cumulative count of the `B` and `+` signs up to each row:

```
select part_number, section,
       min(date), max(date),
       sum(case when sign = '-' then -count else count end) as section_count,
       sum(sum(case when sign = '-' then -count else count end)) over (partition by part_number order by section) as sum
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when sign in ('B', '+') then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by part_number order by date) as section
      from t
     ) t
group by part_number, section;
```